# Can we create input control parameters such as drop-down JasperReports Server professional edition using web UI designer?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using JasperReports Server professional edition. I want create input control parameters such as drop-down. Let us say my drop-down will contain latest seven dates , upon selecting one date my report will come.

Is it possible to create this kind of input control parameter without using jaspersoft studio designer? i.e can we do it on web UI itself?

Please Note : I went through 5.3.2 Adding Input Controls section completely from JasperReports Server User Guide. ( We can do it using Jaspersoft studio designer but I want using web UI designer )